# How can I reduce high incoming voltage 252 V?

Tags: high-voltage

I have a 3 Hp 1 Ph 230 V motor.  The incoming power changed from 242 V to 252 V and now it trips the overload in the control panel. The specs say not to run above 250 V. I’ve checked the motor and tested it on a test panel and all seems fine. Is there any way to reduce the incoming voltage?  The electric company says they are within their acceptable range.

Comment: @DKNguyen it seems that it is a single-phase motor.

Comment: @mkeith Oh I think I might have read 3 Hp as 3 Ph

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the control panel overload is a bit too sensitive. But you might try reducing the size of the start or run capacitor by 10% or so, as it's probably the starting current that trips the overload.

Otherwise, you could utilize a buck transformer to reduce the voltage. The motor probably draws about 12-15 amps, so you could use a 200 VA 240 V to 12 or 16 VAC which will drop the motor voltage to 240 VAC or 236 VAC.

https://electricalacademia.com/transformer/buck-boost-transformer-working-principle/

Comment: Good call on the buck transformer.  I was gonna suggest same!   Very clever transformer application that I've found few people aware of.